# Airdrop NFT's to wallets that are already staking some other NFT's

Tags: nft, staking, airdrop

Is it possible to get the list of wallets that are currently staking a certain NFT and airdrop some new NFT's to them? It is custodial staking. How would you do it?

Comment: Need more info but its possible though

Comment: @maddy sorry for the late response. There is a contract that people are using to stake their NFT's from collection X. Could I somehow get the list of pubkeys of these wallets currently staking, and airdrop them a new NFT from collection Y? Saw people saying this might be something to do with the snapshot but not sure how to go about it.